# Having Trouble Fetching String & Int from Textbox, using Java Swing methods

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a panel for input of the details (student#,student name, unit #, and price per unit) to be put into .txt file with the student # as the filename. My current issue is that I cannot seem to fetch the values using getText() and parseInt as seen below. It is reaching the methods when tried with System.out lines

*edit* managed to get the values to reach the variables, now the writer is my current issue, as it doesn't seem to want to write..

Here is what I've done so far:

```
package javaSwing;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class StudentRegistration extends JFrame{
    static String studentName;
    static String studentNumber ;
    static int units ;
    static int unitcost;
    static int total;

    public StudentRegistration(){
        initUI();
    }
    private void initUI(){
        setTitle("Student Registration");
        setSize(500,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(null);
        add(panel);

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Register Student");
        titleLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,30));
        JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Student No.");
        numberLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Student Name.");
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
        JLabel unitsEn = new JLabel("Units Enrolled:");
        unitsEn.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));

        JLabel unitCost = new JLabel("Per Unit Fee");
        unitCost.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));

        JTextField numberText = new JTextField(30);
        numberText.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
        JTextField nameText = new JTextField(30);
        nameText.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
        JTextField unitsText = new JTextField(30);
        unitsText.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));
        JTextField unitCostText = new JTextField(30);
        unitCostText.setFont(new Font("Calibri",Font.BOLD,20));


        JButton saveButton = new JButton("SAVE");
        saveButton.setToolTipText("Exit application");

        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
                studentName = nameText.getText();
                studentNumber = numberText.getText();
                units = Integer.parseInt(unitsText.getText());
                unitcost = Integer.parseInt(unitCostText.getText());
                total = units*unitcost;
// System.out lines to test values
                System.out.println(studentNumber);
                System.out.println(studentName);
                System.out.println(units);
                System.out.println(unitcost);
                System.out.println(total);
                try {
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter
                            (studentNumber+".txt","UTF-8");
                    writer.println(studentName);
                    writer.println(studentNumber);
                    writer.println(units);
                    writer.println(unitcost);
                    writer.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }   
            }
        });
        setVisible(true);

    titleLabel.setLocation(20,20);
    titleLabel.setSize(300,30);
    numberLabel.setLocation(20,70);
    numberLabel.setSize(300,30);
    nameLabel.setLocation(20,70);
    nameLabel.setSize(300,120);
    unitsEn.setLocation(20,115);
    unitsEn.setSize(300,120);
    unitCost.setLocation(20,155);
    unitCost.setSize(300,120);
    numberText.setLocation(150,70);
    numberText.setSize(300,30);
    nameText.setLocation(150, 115);
    nameText.setSize(300,30);
    unitsText.setLocation(150,160);
    unitsText.setSize(300,30);
    unitCostText.setLocation(150,200);
    unitCostText.setSize(300,30);
    saveButton.setLocation(150,240);
    saveButton.setSize(100,50);

    panel.add(titleLabel);
    panel.add(numberLabel);
    panel.add(numberText);
    panel.add(saveButton);
    panel.add(nameLabel);
    panel.add(nameText);
    panel.add(unitsEn);
    panel.add(unitCost);
    panel.add(unitsText);
    panel.add(unitCostText);



    //writeStudentInfo();
}


}
```

Comment: The line `studentName = nameText.getText();` needs to be executed during saving time, move it before `writer.println(studentName);`. Same for `studentNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the following in your code
1. get all text logic to be written inside the actionPerformed()

```
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            //writeStudentInfo();
            studentNumber = numberText.getText();
            System.out.print("clickec"+studentNumber);
        }
    });
```

2. Write all component at class attribute level. i,e in class attribute section

   `static String studentName;
    static String studentNumber ;
    static int units ;
    static int unitcost;
    static int total;
    JLabel numberLabel = new JLabel("Student No.");`

so that numberLabel is visible inside actionPerformed() method.

Comment: i get errors doing the 2nd part, however the 1st step has helped alot because the values are actually reaching the variables. If you could please check the writer code? it doesnt seem to want to generate a new txt file

Comment: Please try to provide absolute path of the file. example PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/"+studentNumber+".txt","UTF-8");    Also please use writer.flush() before writer.close();

Comment: What does writer.flush do?

Comment: Note: I apologize it was actually working already the writer its just it never showed up in the folder i was expecting, so thanks for the advice above as the path for the file.

Comment: sure please accept the answer by clicking on wright symbol and vote the answer please.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `textfiledname.getText()` method in your program to get the text of the textbox.

```
e.g. String name = t1.getText(); // This will store the value of t1 textbox in name variable.
```